# Adjective of proper noun containing "and"

Tags: adjectives, proper-nouns, toponyms, demonyms

A person from The Turks and Caicus Islands is known as what? Likewise with Trinidad and Tobago, St Kitts and Nevis, São Tomé and Principé, and Bosnia and Herzegovina. http://www.un.org/en/members/

I've heard of "Trinidadian", but isn't that specific to one island? Then again I've heard of Bosnians but not Herzegovinians. In some cases, it isn't even clear what someone from specifically one group of islands is called. Turk? Caicasian?

Comment: In the Commonwealth Games three nights ago, there was a wonderful moment when the island nation of Kiribati won a gold medal in weightlifting. Kiribati is in the mid-Pacific Ocean. It was formerly part of the Gilbert & Ellice Islands. The name Kiribati is derived from the local way of rendering the word 'Gilbert', after the Englishman Thomas Gilbert, who crossed the archipelago in 1788. The Ellice Islands are known as Tuvalu, and they are also competing at Glasgow, along with 71 nations in all comprising one third of the earth's population who have some historic connection with Britain.

Comment: But were they still called the Gilbert and Ellice Islands, heaven only knows how their inhabitants would be described adjectivally.

Comment: These aren’t exactly adjectives, or at least, not **only** adjectives. They get used as nouns, too.

Answer (score 4):

There is no rule. Every place has its own unique ***gentilic***  for the name of the people from there, which is also known as a ***demonym***.  You simply have to look each one up individually, each and every time.

- **Antigua and Barbados**: *Antiguan* or *Barbudan*
- **Bosnia and Herzegovina**: *Bosnian* or *Herzegovinian* or *Bosnia(n)-Herzegovinian* <sup>[[thanks JBJ]](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/188461/adjective-of-proper-noun-containing-and/188463#comment393074_188463)</sup>
- **Saint Kitts and Nevis**: *Kittitian* or *Nevisian*
- **Saint Vincent and the Grenadines**:     *Vincentian* or  *Vincy*
- **São Tomé and Principé**: *São Toméan* or *Santomean*
- **Trinidad and Tobago**: *Trinidadian* or *Tobagonian* or *Trinbagonian*
- **The Turks and Caicos Islands**: *Turks and Caicos Islander*

In a few cases, people have tried to combine them, but that doesn’t look too nice: consider *Trinbagonian* or  *Bosnian-Herzegovinian*.

Sometimes only one part of the double-barrelled part is used, such as with *Santomean*, which skips the *Príncipe* portion altogether.

But if they are actually two places, each place gets its own gentilic.  So for example if you are from Antigua and Barbados, you are still either an *Antiguan* or else a *Barbudan*, not an **Antigua-Barbudan*.

The real question is not the ands but the ors.  In other words, what do you call someone from **Truth or Consequences**, New Mexico?  Best to just say that somebody is *from T or C* and leave it at that.

Comment: For the first one, _Bosnia(n)-Herzegovinian_ is also found, with various variants.

Comment: Westward Ho!an?

Comment: People from *Truth or Consequences* are from truth or (from) consequences. Consequently, their origin is truly somewhat indeterminate, though we can be sure they are from New Mexico.